# javascript function declarations and differences in scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

*I couldnT find an answer easily, so even if this question is a dupe, the answers donT come up using  these keywords.*

I want to know **the difference between the different way of declaring functions** in a sample app.js

```
var foo = function()
{
  //..
}

function bar()
{
  //..
}

var baz= function()
{
  //..
}

function qux()
{
  //..
}

// other??
```

I m also not clear about the scope where I can use each function. Thanks!

Comment: and yet under "related" questions the top two links have exactly what you need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four ways to create a function in JavaScript.

## Function declaration

This will create a variable `foo` in the current scope and assign a named function to it.

```
function foo () {

}
```

Function declarations are hoisted so it doesn't matter where, in the applicable scope, you put them. It is considered good coding practise to define them before you use them though.

## Anonymous function expression

This will create a function without a name and use it in an expression. In this example it is assigned to the variable `something`.

```
something = function () {

};
```

## Named function expression

This is the same as an anonymous function expression except that it has a name, creates a variable of that name in the scope of itself and is [horribly broken](http://kiro.me/blog/nfe_dilemma.html) in older versions of Internet Explorer.

```
something = function foo () {

};
```

## Function constructor

Do not use function constructors. They are `eval` by another name. You can read about them on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) if you're interested.